# advantage of extern-int to int in .h for c language, considering the compiler(gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, header, language-lawyer

before, whey I study C, I know it is recommended to use variable declaration in hearder(.h):

```
extern int a;
```

nowadays, I study a few of compiler, I know "int a" is weak-type, and "int a = 0;" is strong type, and **weak-type could be used for multiple times**, my code bellow works well, though "int num" is called multiple times:

```
// ==== sub.h ==== 
int num; // not use "extern int num;"
void change();
```

```
// ==== sub.c ==== 
#include "sub.h"

int num = 1;

void change()
{
    num = 10;
}
```

```
// ==== main.c ==== 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sub.h"

int main()
{
    printf("before-change: %d\n", num);
    change();
    printf(" after-change: %d\n", num);
}
```

and I run gcc compiler command:

```
gcc main.c sub.c -o app.exe
```

the result is

```
before-change: 1
 after-change: 10
```

my question is that: what is the advantage of "extern int a;" to "int a;" in c-header. (only in c language, I researched this is an issue in c++)

Comment: The difference between `extern int a;` and `int a;` is that the latter is a [tentative definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern), whereas the former is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the advantage of adding "extern C" in my header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265851/whats-the-advantage-of-adding-extern-c-in-my-header-files)

Comment: leotsing, hmmm, with `int num; // not use "extern int num;"`, no compiler error of 2 `int i`: one defined in `main.c` and another in `sub.c`?  Like "multiple definition of `num'"?

Comment: leotsing, was `gcc main.c sub.c -o app.exe` done with `int num; // not use "extern int num;"` or `extern int num; // not use "extern int num;"`

Comment: hi chux. (1) no compiler error of 2 `int i`, as I mentioned, it is 'weak-type', multiple-weak-type is accepted; (2) `gcc main.c sub.c -o app.exe` done with either `int num` or `extern init num` (existing `int num = 1;`)